# Oracle to SQL server Date conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to convert an Oracle SQL query into SQL server query.
But I encountered a problem with the following line :

> AND to_date(to_char(M_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY')) = '27/01/12'

M_DATE :  DATE NOT NULL

I use

> to_char(DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY')

in order to get their data like that : DD-MM-YYYY 00:00:00.000 (data are stocked like : 25/02/12 15:32:06.578)

So I searched on the Internet, but I didn't find any available solution. But I'm not an experienced SQL user, so if anybody know the solution..

Thanks

Comment: `to_date(to_char())` on a column that is already a `DATE` is complete nonsense in Oracle. In your Oracle query you should use `M_DATE = to_date('27/01/12', 'DD/MM/YY'))`

Comment: @MarkBannister: you cannot use to_char() on something that isn't a `DATE` in Oracle - at least not with the format mask given

Comment: Yes, I realised the mask made the difference after posting that comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general when removing any time values from a date I would use Date functions rather than converting to string

```
 DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))
```

instead of

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 103)
```

Although the end result is the same you are maintaining date format and while I have no specific results sets to prove it conclusively I have found this to be much quicker when dealing with large quantities of data.

Comment: On SQL Server 2008 simpler to just cast to `date`. This is sargable too.

Comment: Every day is a school day! I had never used CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) before but have been using 2008 for years. Thanks @MartinSmith

Comment: The solution is : WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR, M_DATE, 103) = '27/01/2012'

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, I would remove the time element of a datetime using trunc - like so:

```
AND trunc(M_DATE) = ...
```

In SQLServer, I would convert to a date - like so:

```
AND convert(date,M_DATE) = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE(), 131)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```
AND convert(varchar(8), M_DATE, 3) = '27/01/12'
```

Of course, that won't work if you have dates from other centuries.

I'm not sure what you mean by "data are stocked like"; be aware that the Microsoft SQL Server `DATE` type [only has a precision of one day](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx).  If you want to have the time as well as the day, you should use the `DATETIME2` [type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx)

Comment: it's better to convert the literal `'27/01/12'` to a date using `to_date`. Then a possible index on m_date could be used by Oracle.

Comment: I believe the questioner is converting Oracle SQL to MS SQL.  However, that's still probably a good point.