# SSIS datatype mismatch

Tags: ssis

I am trying to import from an oracle Source,I have  a date field  both on the source and destination.Its throwing error **"there was an error with the input column on input OLE DB Destination failed with error code oxco209029A occured while processing input "OLE DB  destination input(3554)".**
I am trying to cahnge it to char in the Oracle query and change it to back to date..in the SSIS using data conversion, and it didnt work as well,may be I am doing something wrong,Could you guys have alook at this?I really appreciate it..Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are three of my previous answers on this topic.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11585853/236348

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2231164/236348

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11229159/236348

Comment: Thanks alot @William Todd Salzman,it did solve my problem,the cast oracle script helped me on the Oracle side and I used  data cconversion from the SSIS side.Thanks again guys..

Answer (score 2):

Oracle and SQL Server date types are a known incompatibility.

- [Oracle to SQL server Date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034530/oracle-to-sql-server-date-conversion)
- [Oracle to SQL Server: Date Conversion & Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004577/oracle-to-sql-server-date-conversion-format)
- http://sql-troubles.blogspot.com/2010/02/oracle-vs-sql-server-date-conversion.html
- http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=98943

etc.

You've cast the Oracle type to some string equivalent and SQL Server isn't accepting the input for a (date, datetime, datetime2?) data type. Generally your options are to clean up your cast to be a recognizable date format or add a Derived Column Transformation to change the input string column to the SSIS equivalent. The exact type depends on what your target table has defined.

Comment: Hey@billinkc  Thanks alot for your urgent reply,very helpful indeed,I did use To_Char and the data is there with yyyy-mm-dd format,I have data conversion between the oracle source and dest,using that very field,and I chose the for the data type..date[DT_DATE] ON the SSIS side, and field dest field has datatime data type as well on SSMS,does this bring any picture on what I am doing wrong?Is there a better approach to this?Thanks again guys..